# Creating a datetime range for each category in a dataframe: python/SQL

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe, join

I have a dataframe with columns: ID, Tech, Price and factor (see below). I want to assign this datetime range to each of the 'ID' in this dataframe. Accordingly, I created another datetime dataframe as per my requirements. I have worked on merging dataframes based on the "pandas.merge" function which requires a common key between the dataframes. My datetime dataframe does not include any variable that is common with the parent dataframe to perform the merge operation between dataframes. How can solve this problem?

```
df:
ID      Tech    Price   Factor
100-10A   A     688.3   0.36
100-10B   A     123     0.36
200-11A   A     543     0.34
450-11B   A     688.3   0.34
570-1     B     675     0.31
430-2     B     952     0.28
698-5A    C     52.8    0
129-1     D     177.6   0.08
```

I have created a datetime dataframe (times) that varies hourly.
times:

```
import pandas as pd 
a = pd.date_range(start='2010-01-01 00:00:00', end='2010-01-01 6:00:00', freq = 'H')

pd.DataFrame(a):
a:
    0
0   2010-01-01 00:00:00
1   2010-01-01 01:00:00
2   2010-01-01 02:00:00
3   2010-01-01 03:00:00
4   2010-01-01 04:00:00
5   2010-01-01 05:00:00
6   2010-01-01 06:00:00
```

How can I achieve the date to dataframe mapping in such a case? I want my dataframe to look like below

```
Datetime            ID           Tech       Price       Factor
1/1/2010 0:00       100-10A         A       688.3       0.36
1/1/2010 1:00       100-10A         A       688.3       0.36
1/1/2010 2:00       100-10A         A       688.3       0.36
1/1/2010 3:00       100-10A         A       688.3       0.36
1/1/2010 4:00       100-10A         A       688.3       0.36
1/1/2010 5:00       100-10A         A       688.3       0.36
1/1/2010 6:00       100-10A         A       688.3       0.36
1/1/2010 0:00       100-10B         A       123         0.36
1/1/2010 1:00       100-10B         A       123         0.36
1/1/2010 2:00       100-10B         A       123         0.36
1/1/2010 3:00       100-10B         A       123         0.36
1/1/2010 4:00       100-10B         A       123         0.36
1/1/2010 5:00       100-10B         A       123         0.36
1/1/2010 6:00       100-10B         A       123         0.36
1/1/2010 0:00       200-11A         A       543         0.34
1/1/2010 1:00       200-11A         A       543         0.34
1/1/2010 2:00       200-11A         A       543         0.34
1/1/2010 3:00       200-11A         A       543         0.34
1/1/2010 4:00       200-11A         A       543         0.34
1/1/2010 5:00       200-11A         A       543         0.34
1/1/2010 6:00       200-11A         A       543         0.34
1/1/2010 0:00       450-11B         A       688.3       0.34
1/1/2010 1:00       450-11B         A       688.3       0.34
1/1/2010 2:00       450-11B         A       688.3       0.34
1/1/2010 3:00       450-11B         A       688.3       0.34
1/1/2010 4:00       450-11B         A       688.3       0.34
1/1/2010 5:00       450-11B         A       688.3       0.34
1/1/2010 6:00       450-11B         A       688.3       0.34
1/1/2010 0:00       570-1           B       675         0.31
1/1/2010 1:00       570-2           B       675         0.31
1/1/2010 2:00       570-3           B       675         0.31
1/1/2010 3:00       570-4           B       675         0.31
1/1/2010 4:00       570-5           B       675         0.31
1/1/2010 5:00       570-6           B       675         0.31
1/1/2010 6:00       570-7           B       675         0.31
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to my problem. This can be achieved through the cross join. since thee no key to match, we temporarily assign a key to each if the dfs/ tables and perform a merge between both to perform a cross join:

```
def cartesian_product_basic(left, right):
    return (left.assign(key=1).merge(right.assign(key=1), on='key').drop('key', 1))

result = cartesian_product_basic(df, a)
```